# Annotating wireframes in sketch - how do you do it?

Tags: documentation, wireframe

I've been using the notebook pro plugin for the past few months, but I'm running into tons of issues. (crashes, random inability to add new comments in larger docs, etc)

**What are other techniques for adding annotations in sketch?**

---

Things I'm thinking about doing:

- creating an annotation group and calling things out/writing notes directly on top of the doc. Would show/hide the groups depending on whether or not I want to include annotations in export.
- Making a master doc in Invision for internal use and having annotations live there.

  - As projects grow and evolve, this would be a pain to update.
  - Would be nice to have annotations live outside of the design doc in case of file loss.

---

Help me not buy Omnigraffle :|

Comment: I use invision for annotating my interaction design for dev. I find it very light and it works fine. I don't think I understand your issue. Why is it a pain to update? I update the sketch files all the time with the craft plugin. I am so much happier with this than I was when using Axure!!

Comment: Invision also has a Design System Management tool that allows you to capture visual design of components for reuse - saves sooooo much time!

Comment: Can you clarify what the annotations are for?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is for dev handover/client engagement. There are a couple of things you can do here that I do/have done:

Look into **software**:

- [Zeplin](https://zeplin.io/) is great for this as it automatically numbers comments, you can colour code them, and have hidden ones only the team can see, its also great for dev handover.
- [Abstract](https://www.goabstract.com/) is a version control software for Sketch (works like Git for developers, in that you work on branches and comit it to a master file etc), this can resolve and file loss issues you have as its stored in the cloud and you can work on it straight form there, this is also great for dev handover and allows for comments on designs.
- [Invision](https://www.invisionapp.com/), as you've mentioned it above im assuming you have used this.
- [Marvel](https://marvelapp.com/), very similar to Invision and has its own [Sketch Plugin](https://marvelapp.com/integrations/sketch/).

*All of these have free versions that you can use before having to commit to paying.*

**Plugins**, look into some potential plugins that allow for this. For example https://marcosvid.al/sketch-notebook/

Or, you could as, you say use **Sketch layers/groups** with them on, providing that who ever is using it can get to them easily. Or even a separate artboard or on the side of your designs (on the same artboard) with the annotations.

If you dont already do so, always walkthrough the designs with the clients/developers too so they have a clear understanding.

Comment: I like the sketch layers/seperate artboard idea... I will be trying that for my visual design annoations (like padding etc.) .